# Three js scrolling mesh colors and Z positions on bufferedGeometry

Tags: three.js

I am working with a three js indexed buffered geometry that is in need of some performance improvements.

The visualization I'm working on is essentially a 3D waterfall visualization where each time I receive a new "row" of data I will copy each vertex color and Z position to the row above it, like so:

```
for(let i = this.geometry.attributes.position.count - 1; i >= this.frameWidth; i--){
        let former = i - this.frameWidth;
        this.geometry.attributes.position.setZ(i, this.geometry.attributes.position.getZ(former) );
        this.geometry.attributes.color.setXYZ(i, this.geometry.attributes.color.getX(former), this.geometry.attributes.color.getY(former), this.geometry.attributes.color.getZ(former));
    }
```

Followed by entering the new Row of data where the frame variable corresponds to the new row to be entered:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.frameWidth; i += 1) {
        const color = this.colorMap.current.getColor(frame[i]);
        this.geometry.attributes.color.setXYZ(i, color.r, color.g, color.b);
        this.geometry.attributes.position.setZ(i, frame[i]);
    }

    this.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
    this.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

Being someone whom is more familiar with the works of GPU programming it really seems to me that these for loops can be taken out or done in parallel in some way to vastly improve performance. Is there something I'm missing with threeJS that does these sorts of operations that I'm not aware of?

A second idea that I have is to actually translate the position of the mesh in the Y axes (eliminating the need to copy color and position entries) and re-purposing the vertices of the last row to be the "new" front row where the new data is placed. However it seems that this requires some sort of modification of indices that I'm not exactly sure how it works.

Any ideas and suggestions are extremely helpful :) Thanks!

Comment: Changing all position and color attributes is a slow process because you're re-uploading all that buffer data to the GPU on each update. The higher the number of verts, the slower it'll be. The only alternative is to learn GLSL to write your own custom vertex shader so you could perform all those position calculations in the GPU itself, without re-uploading new data. If you choose this approach, I recommend thebookofshaders.com

Comment: So this definitely seems like the path I'll want to go down, the issue being that within the shader, how would I go about accessing the value of another index within the position and color array? 

It seems that most of the operations that many people use on a shader is a mathematical operation rather than a memory access type of operation. For example, for each index I want to take the Z value of the entry 1024 indexs away, with a similar pattern for the color attribute

I also have tried passing in the position array through a uniform but unfortunately its size is way too large.